# Realizar un split con javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un método en `javascript` el cual dada una url absoluta la convierte en relativa. Para ello estoy intentando realizar un `split` para que la url dada la corte por `\` He buscado por internet y no soy capaz a encontrar nada que funcione. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?.

He probado con lo siguiente, pero no funciona y si pongo solo una `\` genera un error:

```
path.split("\\");
var ultimo=path.lenght;
$('#url-archivo').val(path[ultimo-1]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

espero funcione, puede que no te funcione por que estas escribiendo mal el length.

```
var array = path.split("\\");
var ultimo = array.length;
$('#url-archivo').val(array[ultimo-1]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso :D

Answer (score 0):

En javascript la barra invertida `\` se usa para escapar caracteres de control (o sea para poder poner caracteres de control dentro de un string. Por ejemplo `"\t"` es una tabulación y `"\n"` es un caracter de nueva línea. Javascript siempre que ve una barra invertida entiende que le está dando un significado especial al siguiente caracter.

¿Entonces cómo se pone una barra invertida dentro de un string?. Usando dos barras invertidas `"\\"`.

Es por eso que no te funciona con una. Con dos está bien (dos significa una).

Comment: Gracias por contestar tan rápido. Como indiqué arriba con las dos barras no funciona. No realiza el corte por donde yo quiero.